# Can I switch off the drive OAuth flow?

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a way to switch off the built in flow to handle the OAuth flow myself?

Right now it looks as if the "grant permissions" page appears before the user is getting to my app.

As I'm using App Engine and rely on the UserServer to trigger actions on behalf of the user I have to handle all the OAuth flow myself anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to turn off the install flow; it is however a good feature request and will will be looking into this.

Thanks for the feedback, I'll update this answer when I have more information.